# MySQL Query - get hours per day between two dates

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to get my head around the best way to build a query. I want to get the hours per day for an activity between two dates.

For some background, I'm trying to build a dynamic labour histogram from a table of activities (workpacks). The table `workpacks` has an activity per row with a `start` and `finish` date and number of hours for that activity.

The query takes the total hours for that activity period and in PHP I will divide it by the number of days and 8 worked hours per day to give me the number of people required for the activity that I'll use to plot on a graph.

I'm successfully getting the Hours and Days Days between the activities using:

```
SELECT `manhours`, DATEDIFF(`finish`, `start`) 
from workpacks 
WHERE `project` = 9000 AND `wpid` = 45 AND `finish` > curdate();
```

This gives me 400 hours and 10 days. So 400 / 10 = 40 hours per day / 8 hours per day = 5 people per day for the duration of the activity which is a simple maths calculation I can do in PHP.

I am thinking to do a loop in PHP to run a query for each date to see if the activity is in that period and if so, the hours, but I feel there may be an easier/better way of doing this. Am I missing something obvious, or would a query be more complex than I initially thought and my approach may be best?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve using Excel:

| Project | Workpacks | Start | Finish | Manhours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9000 | Lighting | 45124 | 45135 | 500 |
| 9000 | Small Power | 45119 | 45166 | 2000 |
| 9000 | LV Distribution | 45110 | 45124 | 250 |
| 9000 | Fire Alarm | 45112 | 45121 | 180 |
| 9000 | Intercom | 45118 | 45127 | 100 |
| 9000 | Access Control | 45148 | 45150 | 100 |
| 9000 | CCTV | 45129 | 45138 | 200 |

Note: the above table gets uploaded as CSV to MySQL using PHP.

And then maniupulating that into a table to get the hours per day per activity (in this case using July as the period) and summing the activities on each date in the bottom row then plotting to a graph.
Each cell uses the formula:

```
=ROUND(IF(AND(J$1>$C2,J$1<$D2),$E2/($D2-$C2)/8,0),0)
```

Where cells are described below:

```
=ROUND(IF(AND(date>start date,date<finish date),manhours/(activity duration)/8,0),0)
```

| 03/07/23 | 04/07/23 | 05/07/23 | 05/07/27 | 06/07/23 | 07/07/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lighting | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Small Power | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| LV Distribution | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Fire Alarm | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| Intercom | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Access Control | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| CCTV | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Operatives | 0 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 5 |

And generating something like this but in the Google Graph API:

[image: Labour Histogram]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you add sample data and the desired result?

Comment: you can do the math calculation in SQL, too: `SELECT manhours / DATEDIFF(finish, start) / 8 AS people_per_day`

Comment: I think you want to join this query with a table that has all the dates. `JOIN date_table AS dt ON dt.date BETWEEN start AND finish`

Comment: Thanks - I've added my offline excel solution to explain better.

Comment: Can't really do another table with dates as typically the webpage will just be today's date + 4 weeks or 'x' months as a lookahead.

Comment: A simple example of a table with all the dates for the next 2 months, is: https://dbfiddle.uk/0rUlkvgg

Comment: @Luuk This is amazing and never knew you could do that. Thanks

Comment: @Luuk - I've got my query now, but don't know how to add in the dates like you've shown. My query is: SELECT `project`,`wpid`,(`manhours`/ DATEDIFF(`finish`, `start`)) AS hoursperday FROM workpacks WHERE `start` < curdate() AND `finish` > curdate() AND `project` = 9000; but instead of curdate I want the date from your column. Any guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/00fO9Mxi)   You may need to add the data for the table `workpacks` yourself...

Comment: @Luuk - that's great. I made a few minor tweaks, but if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @TomC: sorry, too much work to create an answer for this.... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working with special thanks to some help from Barmar and Luuk as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
   SELECT current_date() as date
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   FROM dates
   WHERE date < DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL 8 WEEK)
)
SELECT
   `project`,
   `wpid`,
   (sum(round(manhours/ DATEDIFF(finish, start),0))) AS hoursperday,
   dates.date
FROM workpacks
CROSS JOIN dates
WHERE start < dates.date AND finish > dates.date 
GROUP BY dates.date;
```